# How to take snap shot /print screen of client area and save as image in database?

Tags: html, screenshot

I have asked this question before but now with more elaborate way. I working on this for past two months and the result is zero.
 All i need is .i am allowing the client to create a diagram by dropping the images on a div whose background is a esri Map . When they clik save ,the snapshot of the whole div has to be saved as image in database.

If some one could suggest activx plug-in for taking print screen ot capture the client screen .pls suggest

EDITED
I tried something like savefrom URL ,but i dont want to save the whole page ,only div.

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse();
```

and

```
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        // Download home page data.
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading " + remoteUri);
        // Download the Web resource and save it into a data buffer.
        byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(remoteUri);
```

Comment: Using what language/platform?

Comment: @Pekka I am using asp.net,C# ,Javascript. my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349887/graphics-copyfromscreen-web-application-the-handle-is-invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be more focused on extracting/scraping the div locations (that the user's dragged) and passing them off to the server so it can be processed. The processing would include creating a `Bitmap`, placing the ESRI Map as the background (with any applicable off-sets), then overlaying the "movable/dragged" DIVs [more specifically, the images that are associated to them] on top of that base, then exporting the whole entry as a "Screenshot".

You should be looking more at reproducing the outcome instead of capturing it (at least if this is planned for a web-client implementation).

Comment: If everyone can excuse the fact that I "used" other people's images, here is what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/jFJtu/ most of the information you need to replicate the outcome is displayed after "View Report" is clicked.

Comment: ..If i recreate it using the Bitmap,how i can i male sure of the position ?.

Comment: @Vani: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Please see my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148290/how-to-re-create-a-image-using-the-attributes-in-server-sidegraphics-drawimage . I have to bring the images exactly in the same position as a bitmap or something.